# Enter null into database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert Null in to one of my fields in my table, but the field just adds a 0 instead.

How can I get it to be a Null?

The type of the field is int and the default value is (NULL).

```
$query = "INSERT INTO article (article_title, article_credits, article_excerpt, article_body, article_img_list, article_img_main, article_published, article_date, article_modified, article_author, article_gallery_id, article_gallery_title) ".
                    "SELECT '".$db->escape($post['title'])."', '".json_encode($credits)."','".$db->escape($post['excerpt'])."','".$db->escape($post['article'])."','".$db->escape($articleImageListName)."','".$db->escape($articleImageMainName)."','".$published."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($post['date']))."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."', email, '".$db->escape($post['gallery'])."', 'View gallery'".
                    "FROM sm_users WHERE id = ".$acl->getLoggedInUserId()."";
```

Comment: Is this the primary key or fk?

Comment: Change the type to varchar

Comment: The field you are inserting to either has default value or numeric datatype with `NOT NULL` property

Comment: Skip that field while insert(query).

Comment: How exactly are you inserting?

Comment: Which field is it? You can make an update on your field after your INSERT INTO .. SELECT. Like: `UPDATE article SET field = NULL WHERE field = '';`

Answer (score 2):

The field you are inserting to either has default value or numeric datatype with NOT NULL property.

If you want to insert `NULL` to that field you can:

1. Skip that field on insert.
2. Remove default value.
3. Change/check property `NULL?`.
4. Change index/FK/PK (if declared as PK/FK or INDEX).

Answer (score 0):

What is your current try?

This should work:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_field = NULL WHERE id = <id>;
```

Answer (score 0):

to INSERT NULL to a column if the column has the NOT NULL constraint then it won't be possible; but otherwise this is fine:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyIntColumn) VALUES(NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Null as in value null or just the string null? You can have "" (which is seen as null by a table, because you allow nullables then in that column) in your tables, but if you want null specifically I would put the string null in there, or just let it check if the cell is empty ("").

See Lebugg's answer for the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for single column:

INSERT INTO `database`.`table` () VALUES ();

If you want to update then:

```
update table set field = NULL where something = something
```

Don't put `NULL` inside quotes in your update statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to set the default value of the column to be `NULL`. Then if you don't insert a value your column will contain `NULL`. Keep in mind that If the particular column is a PK/FK it will not be possible.

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = NULL WHERE id = {id};
```

Comment: This does not work. I have to insert a value. Either a number 1,2,3 etc or ''.

Comment: Updated original post with query

Comment: which column do you want to insert NULL

Comment: article_gallery_id. But sometimes a number will go in here. When it should be null the post value is ''. Otherwise it's 1 or 2 or 45 etc.